# How much EXP does Endless Corridors give?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

How much account rank EXP does the [Endless Corridors](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/mission.asp?m=1421) Special Dungeon reward if completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's great for testing out new teams and practicing orb matching, the Endless Corridors dungeon alone gives no rewards at all.  If this wasn't the case, a person with a sufficiently strong team could rank up indefinitely without spending any stamina.

But if you complete that dungeon, as well as the versions without hearts or Awoken skills (same enemies though), you will get a magic stone as a one-time reward similarly to completing other single sets of dungeons.

I would imagine that a similar thing holds for the True Endless Corridors set of dungeons as well.